# Why some services got masked in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, services

On an Ubuntu 20.04 installation, how can I find out, *why* some services got masked? There's only answers about specific services, but I can't find any info about how to troubleshoot that behavior.

For now I got these services masked:

```
alsa-utils.service                                                        masked          enabled
apache-htcacheclean.service                                               masked          enabled
apache2.service                                                           masked          enabled
brltty.service                                                            masked          enabled
cryptdisks-early.service                                                  masked          enabled
cryptdisks.service                                                        masked          enabled
hwclock.service                                                           masked          enabled
mysql.service                                                             masked          enabled
pulseaudio-enable-autospawn.service                                       masked          enabled
rc.service                                                                masked          enabled
rcS.service                                                               masked          enabled
saned.service                                                             masked          enabled
sudo.service                                                              masked          enabled
x11-common.service                                                        masked          enabled
phpsessionclean.timer                                                     masked          enabled
```

`sudo` works fine btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, these services are masked because they correspond to initscripts which are not supposed to be used with systemd, because their systemd equivalent has a different name or is handled differently.

For example, `alsa-utils` is masked because with systemd, `/etc/init.d/alsa-utils` shouldn’t be used; instead, the `alsa-restore` service restores the sound card settings with systemd. Likewise, `saned` is masked because with `systemd`, the SANE daemon is handled by `saned.socket` and `saned@.service`.

To determine whether a masked service is a “system property”, *i.e.* made that way by the distribution, or a local change, check whether they are masked in `/lib/systemd/system`:

```
$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/alsa-utils.service /lib/systemd/system/saned.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec  7  2020 /lib/systemd/system/alsa-utils.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 25  2021 /lib/systemd/system/saned.service -> /dev/null
```

Masked units are linked to `/dev/null`; the above shows that the distribution’s maintainers set the units up in this way. If such links don’t show up in `/lib/systemd/system`, they’ll be in `/etc/systemctl/system`, and that indicates that the local system administrator masked them.